# Использование множественного числа первого лица вместо единственного

Tags: местоимение

Можно ли, будучи автором художественного произведения, научно-попклярной заметки, эссе, употреблять местоимение "мы" вместо "я"? Частое напоминание о себе ("я") создаёт впечатление нескромности, кичливости автора.

Пример: вместо "Заключая данное произведение, я бы хотел..." — "Заключая данное произведение, мы бы хотели..."

Answer (score 1):

Тогда это будет говорить о том, что несколько людей участвовало. Таким образом можно соврать, чтобы эта заметка выглядела авторитетнее. Ведь к одному человеку меньше доверия.

Для научного стиля вообще характерно отсутствие лица — "хотелось бы". Иногда пишут от третьего лица:
*Авторы данной статьи пришли к следующим выводам...*
А в художественном произведении автор про себя не говорит.

Лучше так оформить ваш пример:
*Подводя итоги, стоит/необходимо отметить...*

Comment: В своём сочинении на эстетическую тему я использовал конструкции вроде "Возьмёмся теперь рассуждать...", "Сразу же отвергнем предположение", "Мы берём от этих произведений средства, которые...", "Как мы бы могли заключить данное произведение?" — во всех случаях преполагается, что все предлагаемые действия выполняются автором и читателем совместно.

Comment: Не то что совместно, а сказано в общем, от второго лица. Но заканчивать произведение совместно автор и читатель точно не могут.

Comment: Пример: *Посмотрим, что здесь такое.* Так человек может сказать даже самому себе. Но "мы бы хотели..." для такого никак не подходит. "Возьмёмся теперь рассуждать..." лучше заменить на "давайте теперь порассуждаем" (так более культурно).

Comment: Там речь идёт о "дерзновении", подразумевается, что мы не имеем полного права об этом рассуждать, так как не подготовлены теоретически — поэтому "Возьмёмся..."

Comment: Данный глагол не передаёт этого. Словарное значение: Приняться за какое-либо дело. Ближе это: *Попробуем теперь порассуждать.*